# Nix Derivation Handle Access to System File

Tags: nix, nixos

I'm trying to create a derivation for a Python GTK3 application [TLPUI](https://github.com/d4nj1/TLPUI).

It seems that as a part of its build it tries to read /etc/tlp.conf which breaks due to sandboxing.

Here is my default.nix for the package.

```
{ lib, fetchFromGitHub, cairo, gobject-introspection, gtk3, python3, python38Packages, tlp, wrapGAppsHook }:

python3.pkgs.buildPythonApplication rec {
  pname = "tlpui";
  version = "1.3.1-5";

  src = fetchFromGitHub {
    owner = "d4nj1";
    repo = "TLPUI";
    rev = "${pname}-${version}";
    sha256 = "1km3xb1slw7cg7bii1wrgn34s42y820w03wmk1nm63csmbdvin14";
  };

  nativeBuildInputs = [
    cairo
    gobject-introspection
    gtk3
    python38Packages.pygobject3
    python38Packages.pycairo
    tlp
    wrapGAppsHook
  ];

  meta = {
    description = "Better lighting for Linux. Open source GUI for xflux";
    homepage = "https://justgetflux.com/linux.html";
    license = lib.licenses.gpl2; 

    maintainers = [ lib.maintainers.ciferkey ];
    platforms = lib.platforms.linux;
  };
}
```

The build fails with the following message:

```
writing TLPUI.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to TLPUI.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing entry points to TLPUI.egg-info/entry_points.txt
writing top-level names to TLPUI.egg-info/top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'TLPUI.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'TLPUI.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
running build_ext
Error: cannot read user configuration from /etc/tlp.conf or /etc/default/tlp.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nix_run_setup", line 8, in <module>
    exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\\r\\n', '\\n'), __file__, 'exec'))
  File "setup.py", line 3, in <module>
    setup(
  File "/nix/store/y7a5rsd9g4nkxizd8mnrmr19z0q67k8x-python3.8-setuptools-47.3.1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 161, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "/nix/store/v72cj06nk69cynckz2s12rhar25k1h7v-python3-3.8.5/lib/python3.8/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/nix/store/v72cj06nk69cynckz2s12rhar25k1h7v-python3-3.8.5/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/nix/store/v72cj06nk69cynckz2s12rhar25k1h7v-python3-3.8.5/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/nix/store/y7a5rsd9g4nkxizd8mnrmr19z0q67k8x-python3.8-setuptools-47.3.1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/test.py", line 238, in run
    self.run_tests()
  File "/nix/store/y7a5rsd9g4nkxizd8mnrmr19z0q67k8x-python3.8-setuptools-47.3.1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/test.py", line 256, in run_tests
    test = unittest.main(
  File "/nix/store/v72cj06nk69cynckz2s12rhar25k1h7v-python3-3.8.5/lib/python3.8/unittest/main.py", line 100, in __init__
    self.parseArgs(argv)
  File "/nix/store/v72cj06nk69cynckz2s12rhar25k1h7v-python3-3.8.5/lib/python3.8/unittest/main.py", line 124, in parseArgs
    self._do_discovery(argv[2:])
  File "/nix/store/v72cj06nk69cynckz2s12rhar25k1h7v-python3-3.8.5/lib/python3.8/unittest/main.py", line 244, in _do_discovery
    self.createTests(from_discovery=True, Loader=Loader)
  File "/nix/store/v72cj06nk69cynckz2s12rhar25k1h7v-python3-3.8.5/lib/python3.8/unittest/main.py", line 154, in createTests
    self.test = loader.discover(self.start, self.pattern, self.top)
  File "/nix/store/v72cj06nk69cynckz2s12rhar25k1h7v-python3-3.8.5/lib/python3.8/unittest/loader.py", line 349, in discover
    tests = list(self._find_tests(start_dir, pattern))
  File "/nix/store/v72cj06nk69cynckz2s12rhar25k1h7v-python3-3.8.5/lib/python3.8/unittest/loader.py", line 405, in _find_tests
    tests, should_recurse = self._find_test_path(
  File "/nix/store/v72cj06nk69cynckz2s12rhar25k1h7v-python3-3.8.5/lib/python3.8/unittest/loader.py", line 483, in _find_test_path
    tests = self.loadTestsFromModule(package, pattern=pattern)
  File "/nix/store/y7a5rsd9g4nkxizd8mnrmr19z0q67k8x-python3.8-setuptools-47.3.1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/test.py", line 55, in loadTestsFromModule
    tests.append(self.loadTestsFromName(submodule))
  File "/nix/store/v72cj06nk69cynckz2s12rhar25k1h7v-python3-3.8.5/lib/python3.8/unittest/loader.py", line 154, in loadTestsFromName
    module = __import__(module_name)
  File "/build/source/tlpui/__main__.py", line 11, in <module>
    Gtk.StyleContext.add_provider_for_screen(
TypeError: Argument 0 does not allow None as a value
builder for '/nix/store/qmimb5pixjxijpjsg0bn310ybk6pa2lq-tlpui-1.3.1-5.drv' failed with exit code 1
error: build of '/nix/store/qmimb5pixjxijpjsg0bn310ybk6pa2lq-tlpui-1.3.1-5.drv' failed
```

Note the error "Error: cannot read user configuration from /etc/tlp.conf or /etc/default/tlp."

This configuration file maps to the following soft link chain: /etc/tlp.conf -> /etc/static/tlp.conf -> /nix/store/203msjwrf88ly6c1f5pavcgsk6icwfjf-etc-tlp.conf

1. Why is the hash-name for the configuration file end with "etc-tlp" rather than just "tlp"?
2. Is it possible to make my derivation definition depend on "etc-tlp" and then create some kind of mapping so the build sees the file under /etc? Is this the wrong way to think about the problem?

Comment: As maintainer of the software -- whose code hardcodes `/etc/tlp.conf`? Can you patch it to honor an environment variable with an alternate location, or check if it would already honor such a variable if one were set?

Comment: ... To answer the question if where `etc-tlp.conf` comes from you'd want to find the Nix module creating it (assuming that it is indeed a NixOS module). But for a derivation it's bad form to not be self-contained at build time, so where the file comes from at runtime isn't particularly relevant. Personally, I'd call it a bug if the upstream tool you're writing a UI for can't be installed or used by folks without write access to `/etc`, and would hope that its maintainers agree.

Comment: I've opened an issue in the TLPUI project to see if the path for it can be made configurable: https://github.com/d4nj1/TLPUI/issues/86

Comment: Looks like it should be solved: https://github.com/d4nj1/TLPUI/issues/86#issuecomment-774146289